# Is there a Plants Vs Zombies PC version with local co-op?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

My girlfriend is a big Plants Vs Zombies fan since she played it in co-op mode with her roommate on PS3.

It would be great to play this together, but I only own a PC.

Is there any PC version of this game for that has local co-op mode for two Gamepad controllers? I checked out Plants Vs Zombies GOTY edition, but could not find any option for this there.

Are we out of luck on the PC?

Answer (score 3):

Checking the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plants_vs._Zombies#Game_modes) article on the game, it is stated that:

> The **PlayStation Network** and **Xbox Live Arcade** version of the game includes 5 multiplayer modes, both co-operative and competitive, ...

So, no, the PC version doesn't have co-op mode.

<sup>1 - Disclaimer: I don't play the game.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Reading this article of pvz versus mode wiki fandom
https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Versus_Mode

It says that is is only available on Nintendo DS, Xbox 360, Xbox One, and PlayStation3.

However there are other ways to play PVZ Coop and Versus Mode on computer, such as using an emulator for PlayStation3, which I have been able to play that game mode on computer. Using remote access software, I can play with people online/remotely.